# ¿Cómo puedo concatenar una variable dentro del nombre de una ruta de archivo en Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, archivo, rutas, concatenación

Tengo un procedure en el cual defino una variable tipo varchar la cual quiero que se concatene dinámicamente a una ruta de un archivo que creare. El procedure recibe como parámetro esa variable. Algo como esto quiero hacer:

```
    Create Procedure Sp_Documentacion
    @nFile varchar(50)
    As
    Begin
    Alter Database DB_XYZ
     Add File
     (
      Name = [@nFile]
      Filename = 'M:\Prueba_Doc\'+@nFile+'.ndf',
          Size = 3072 KB,
          Maxsize = Unlimited,
          Filegrowth = 1024 KB,
      ) TO Filegroup FG_Doc;
```

De tal modo que cuando ejecute mi procedure y le de el nombre. Automáticamente me cree el archivo con el nombre que ingrese y en la ruta indicada.

El error que me da es el siguiente: Incorrect sintax near '+' ..... aparentemente solo es error de sintaxis, y no me permite crear el procedimiento.

Comment: Y ya probaste ese procedimiento? Te dio algún problema? Que error encontraste? Qué problema tienes con ese código?

Comment: Ps el error que me da es : Incorrect sintax near  '+'..... aparentemente solo es error de sintaxis, y no me permite crear el procedimiento.

Comment: Procura siempre poner el error completo como parte de tu pregunta; copias y pegas el texto del error en la pregunta. Eso va a facilitar las respuestas oportunas

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estos parámetros no permiten el uso de variables. Esto debido a que no es algo común que se automatice la modificación de bases de datos. Por ello, el recurso habitual es el de generar completamente el código dinámico.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_Documentacion
(
    @nFile varchar(50)
)
AS
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = REPLACE( N'ALTER DATABASE [DB_XYZ] 
    ADD FILE ( NAME = N''<<@nFile>>'', 
                FILENAME = N''M:\Prueba_Doc\<<@nFile>>.ndf'' , 
                SIZE = 3072KB , 
                MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
                FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [FG_Doc]', '<<@nFile>>', @nFile);

PRINT @SQL; --Para verificar    
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

GO
```

Comment: Y donde ingreso el @nfile?

Comment: El valor de `@nFile` va a reemplazar la cadena `<<@nFile>>` en la cadena más larga. Por eso usamos REPLACE.

Comment: Me referia a donde ingresas al ejecutar el procedure el <<@nFile>>. En tu ejemplo pones execute sp '@sq'l? disculpa si quizas no entiendo bien, pero yo requeria al executar el procedure darle el <<@nfile>> como entrada y que me cree el archivo.

Comment: Depende de como lo llames, desde SQL puedes ejecutar `EXEC Sp_Documentacion @nFile = 'NombreDelArchivo';`